# Android: Custom View in ScrollView

Tags: android

I created custom `View` similar to `SeekBar`. Now when I touch regular `SeekBar` and slide it work even I move finger out of `SeekBar`. But when I touch my custom `View` and move finger out of it `ScrollView` start moving and my `View` do not recieve `MotionEven` any more.

How can I make it acting same way as `SeekBar`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable touch event of the parent view when the touch event is cached by you view, like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return false;
    }
```